Python - Raspberry Pi as BLE sender for sensor data
I'm using my RaspberryPi as a device that tracks various sensor data. Now I want to create a Mobile App (Flutter) to read the data in real time using bluetooth low energy (BLE).
I know that there are many tutorials out there, but all of them are more or less to complex. I need a really really simple python script that does the following:

Wait for a device that wants to connect with the RPi
Connect with the device
Send every x seconds the current values to the connected device

I tried out bluepy and did the following: I created a Peripheral object and called peripheral.writeCharacteristic(0x0011, b"Hello World", withResponse=True) in an endless loop every 5 seconds. But what about the connection part?
Also I have one more question: Where can I set the name of my Raspberry for the connection with other BLE devices? Cause right now when I use a BLE Scanner mobile app, it finds a lot of devices, but most of them have the name "N/A" and my Raspberry is not showing up.

maybe you could also ask on similar portal for Raspberry or forum Raspberry Pi - especially for name for BLE device.

Bluepy cannot create device to be in BLE peripheral role.Creating a peripheral has a couple of things that need to be created (advertisement and BLE server app) and then tell the BlueZ daemon where to find them. Lots of opportunity to go wrong and when it does, the error messages aren't always that helpful. The BlueZ API is based on D-Bus for communicating to and from the BlueZ daemon. D-Bus can look a little daunting if you have come across such things before. Anyway, the following does a good job of introducing all of this https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/

There is a Raspberry Pi Python Bluetooth library here
https://github.com/petzval/btferret
See section 3.7 in the documentation for LE server details, and the le_server.py file. This code sets up a server and its characteristics, and sends a notification every 5 seconds. Notifications must be enabled from the client first. The Pi name is set in the devices.txt file (My Pi here).
#Separate devices.txt file defines characteristics
#
#DEVICE = My Pi         TYPE=MESH    NODE=1  ADDRESS = B8:27:EB:F1:50:C3
#  PRIMARY_SERVICE = 1800
#    LECHAR = Device name  PERMIT=06  SIZE=06  UUID=2A00   ; index 0
#  PRIMARY_SERVICE = 112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF00
#    LECHAR = My data  PERMIT=16  SIZE=16 UUID=ABCD        ; index 1 notify 


import btfpy


def callback(clientnode,operation,cticn):

  if(operation == btfpy.LE_CONNECT):
    # clientnode has just connected
    print("Connected")
  elif(operation == btfpy.LE_DISCONNECT):
    # clientnode has just disconnected
    print("Disconnected")
    return(btfpy.SERVER_EXIT)
    
  elif(operation == btfpy.LE_TIMER):
    # The server timer calls here every timerds deci-seconds 
    # clientnode and cticn are invalid
    # This is called by the server not a client  
    # Writing the characteristic sends it as a notification
    btfpy.Write_ctic(btfpy.Localnode(),1,"Hello world",0)   
    pass
   
  return(btfpy.SERVER_CONTINUE)  


if btfpy.Init_blue("devices.txt") == 0:
  exit(0)

  # Set My data (index 1) value  
btfpy.Write_ctic(btfpy.Localnode(),1,"Hello world",0)    

btfpy.Le_server(callback,50)   # timerds = 5 seconds
    
btfpy.Close_all()


